# How many spells a day does a character get?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, class

I know that this a very juvenile question, but I began to doubt my understanding of the rule when reading [this answer to another of my questions](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/71242/can-you-sell-constructed-items). So when looking at [a Wizard's spells per day](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/wizard) in *Pathfinder*, are the spells for each section the grand total of casts that the wizard has, or do **all** the casts between levels get added together? For instance, would a level 5 wizard have 3 first level spells per day, or would they have 11?

Comment: You might want to explain what in that answer confused you, since answers to this will probably not explain the confusing part unless you explain it. (I think I see where the confusion is coming from, but I'm not sure because I'm forced to guess.)

Comment: Clarified on my answer to the linked question.

Comment: @LegendaryDude Nice, thank you! Now it's preserved for the ages. :)

Comment: It might be better to phrase the question as 'How many first-level spells can my wizard cast per day?', since I think that's what you're actually looking for.  I'm not editing because I'm not *sure*, though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**A 5th level wizard can cast 3 1st level spells per day.**

When looking at a class table just look at the row for the level of your character, all other rows are ignored.

Comment: Except for the 'Special' column, where new class features (or expansions of an old one) are added to the list of features your character has.

Comment: Thanks, I got an answer in my other question that said something about having 36 first level casts and I wanted to be sure

Comment: @Areadbhair The 36 first-level casts mentioned in that other question were referring to the cleric using all of their spell slots, not just the first-level slots, to cast that same first-level spell over and over. Technically, by that metric, a 5th level wizard can cast 6 lvl1 spells per day, not including bonus slots, but 2 of those spells would be in lvl2 slots, and one in a lvl3 slot. Only 3 of them would be in slots for which lvl1 spells are the highest that slot can accommodate.

Answer (score 1):

To figure out how many spells per day a character of a spell-casting class can cast, you consult the following information:

First, consult the row in their class table corresponding to their current level.  A first-level Wizard can cast at least 3 1st-, 2 2nd-, and 1 3rd-level spell per day.

Add spells-per-day for exceptional ability scores.  To cast any spells, a Wizard needs at least an Int of 11, but 16 or 18 would be more common.  If we assume our example wizard has an intelligence of 16, he gains one each 1st-, 2nd-, and 3rd-level spell.

Finally, add spells-per-day for other class features, feats, and so on that grant them.  (For example, specialist wizards get an additional spell of each level.)  Let's assume that our example wizard is a universalist with a familiar rather than a bonded item and has no feats that change his spell slot selection.

So our example wizard can cast 4 1st-, 3 2nd-, and 2 3rd-level spells.  But if all he wants to do is cast 1st-level spells all day, he has an important tactical option:  **he can prepare 1st-level spells in higher-level slots** (*CRB* 218, 'Spell Slots').

Perhaps our wizard is too lazy to carry a whole bunch of loot out of the dungeon, and so he wants to cast as many *floating disks* as possible in a day.  He could fill all nine of his slots with *floating disk*.